# Bash, Concatenating 2 strings to reference a 3rd variable

Tags: string, bash, variables, concatenation

I have a bash script I am having some issues with concatenating 2 variables to call a 3rd.

Here is a simplification of the script, but the syntax is eluding me after reading the docs.

```
server_list_all="server1 server2 server3";
var1 = "server";
var2 = "all";

echo $(($var1_list_$var2));
```

This is about as close as I get to the right answer, it acknowledges the string and tosses an error on tokenization.

```
syntax error in expression (error token is "server1 server2 server3....
```

Not really seeing anything in the docs for this, but it should be doable.

EDIT: Cleaned up a bit

Comment: Please see [BashFAQ/006](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The [Bash Reference Manual explains how you can use a neat feature of parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to do some indirection.  In your case, you're interested in finding the contents of a variable whose name is defined by two other variables:

```
server_list_all="server1 server2 server3"
var1=server
var2=all
combined=${var1}_list_${var2}

echo ${!combined}
```

The exclamation mark when referring to `combined` means "use the variable whose name is defined by the contents of `combined`"

Comment: Thanks so much!  I tried to one shot it one line using the !, but kept getting a substitution error. So you have to use an intermediate variable.  Thanks again!

Comment: So is there really no way to do this without creating a new variable?

Comment: @TimothySwan, `eval "echo \`echo \\$\\{${var1}_list_${var2}\}\`"` but that's just nasty.

Comment: Can you concatenate `var1` and `var2` and set that value to `combined` in a way similar to this: `combined=${var1}+${var2}`? I know this doesn't work.

Answer (score 8):

The Advanced Bash Scripting Guide has the answer for you (http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ivr.html). You have two options, the first is classic shell:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 server_list_all="server1 server2 server3";
 var1="server";
 var2="all";

 server_var="${var1}_list_${var2}"
 eval servers=\$$server_var;

 echo $servers
```

Alternatively you can use the bash shortcut ${!var}

```
 #!/bin/bash

 server_list_all="server1 server2 server3";
 var1="server";
 var2="all";

 server_var="${var1}_list_${var2}"
 echo ${!server_var}
```

Either approach works.