# Build Bash variable name

Tags: bash, macos, sh

I want to create a function for colored output (just to learn bash a little better)

Here is what works

```
ESC_SEQ="\x1b["
# foreground red
FG_RED="${ESC_SEQ}31;"
# background yellow
BG_YELLOW="43;"
# style bold
FS_BOLD="1m"
# echo
echo -e "${FG_RED}${BG_YELLOW}${FS_BOLD}Hello World!"
```

No i try to build the function

```
function ext_echo() 
{
    // lets say $1 is RED, $2 is YELLOW, $3 is BOLD
    // so is need something like ...
    echo -e "${FG_$1}${BG_$2}${FS_$3}Hello World!"
}
```

#### How can i build my echo execution from that parameters?

Comment: Might a map/associative array help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script should be a good enough starting point:

```
#!/bin/bash


ext_echo()
{
  declare -A colors

  colors=(
    [red]="<red>"
    [blue]="<blue>"
  )

  for c in "$@"; do
    echo ${colors[$c]}
  done
}

ext_echo red blue
```

**output**

```
<red>
<blue>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
export ESC_SEQ="\e["
export YELLOW="43m"

function format_text() 
{
  BG="$ESC_SEQ$1"
  echo -e "${BG}Hello World!"
}

format_text $YELLOW
```

I don't know how and if it's possible without temporary variable. All [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990436/bash-concatenating-2-strings-to-reference-a-3rd-variable) I found use tmp variable to achieve it.

Comment: This does not work?!

Comment: @dknaack You're coloring parameters seem to be wrong. I just showed you how to join strings to extract callable variable.  Yellow is `\e[43m` not `43;` http://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting#background1

Comment: On the mac its "\x1b[" and on linux its "\e"

Comment: But thats not the problem. In your sample i want AA to be "YELLOW"

Comment: @dknaack I wasn't aware of it. I updated my example to work on Linux, it should be clear now how to convert it to OSX

Comment: Sorry but as i mentioned in my question is the value of a argument passed to a function. 

$COLOR="YELLOW"

Comment: @dknaack Just replace variable YELLOW with function input?

Comment: ;) no that does not work. I have a "const" called BG_YELLOW which contains the value "\e[43m;" ... no i want a function where the user can pass in "YELLOW". No i build the variable and want to use it in echo -e